# swift нажатие кнопки через определенное время

Tags: swift

есть три кнопки, нужно сделать так, что бы они при нажатии на одну из них становились неактивными на 3 секунды допустим, как это реализовать можно? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

1) Делаем кнопку неактивной:

```
button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

2) Делаем задержку на включение активности:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
   self.button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Можно попробовать с помощью таймера.